# Installing a SSL Certificate on Express (Node js)

Tags: node.js, express, ssl

im trying to setup a AlphaSSL WildCard Certificate on a express server on a sub-domain

I'm trying start a blank app on ssl like so:

```
const options = {
       key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/privatekey.pem','utf8'),
       cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname +  '/certificate.pem','utf8'),
       ca: fs.readFileSync(__dirname +  '/intermediate.pem','utf8'),
      };


https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.send('Hello World');
}).listen(80);
```

But the page returns me a ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE, same if i pass my final app on the createServer, and without the ssl

Answer (score 0):

Probably You do not need to use 'utf8' parameter for SSL keys while reading files. The need to get byte array as content, not a string.